# meta_query and strange orderby behaviour

Tags: meta-query

this is my problem query, which picks all future or pending events.

Note that some posts only have _startdate without _enddate (1-day events).

```
$args = array( 
'post_type'=> 'events', 
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
    'key' => '_startdate',
    'value' => $today,
    'type' => 'DATE',
    'compare' => '>='
    ),
    array(
    'key' => '_enddate',
    'type' => 'DATE',
    'value' => $today,
    'compare' => '>='
    ),
    'relation' => 'OR',
    ),
'meta_key'=> '_city', 
'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
'order' => 'ASC',
) ;
```

Everything works great until I change **_city** to **_startdate** or **_enddate**.

Can you please help me with this query (to sort by _startdate ) ? Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Seems that you cannot sort by the same metakeys that are being compared in a relationship?

Comment: Actually, it does not seem that sorting with the SAME metakey names is the problem. Just tried adding another custom field to create another start date with a different metakey name (2 start dates by different names) and that does not allow sorting either. Seems I can either do the combined query OR sort, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'events',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_startdate',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_enddate',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE',
        ),
        'relation' => 'OR',
    ),
);
function jumpin_thru_hoops( $a ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $a = $wpdb->postmeta.'.meta_value+0 ASC';
    return $a;
}
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'jumpin_thru_hoops' );
$upcoming = new WP_Query( $args );
// or
$upcoming = get_posts( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'jumpin_thru_hoops' );
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace `'meta_key'=> '_city'` with `'meta_key'=> '_startdate'`.

Comment: That's the problem: when you change _city to _startdate, it reverts to sorting by post date.

Comment: Are you sure post_date doesn't have the same value as the _startdate?

Comment: I'm sure it is not the same value.

Comment: I've tried to report this same bug, but couldn't explain it well enough

Comment: @WraithKenny Link?